# Stereo Calibration of two images with cameras of different resolution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, kinect, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

I just started with camera calibration and I am trying to perform camera calibration of a pair of cameras. Camera 1 has a high resolution of 1980 X 1080 and the second one has a lower resolution of 512 X 412.

It is not possible to make the cameras capture at different resolution to what they are set at.

So now I only have the images to play with.

Anyone has any idea on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you would save yourself a lot of headache by using two identical cameras.

In theory it is possible to calibrate such a stereo pair, i. e. estimate the intrinsics and the extrinsics of each camera, and the rotation and translation between the cameras.  However, you would not be able to rectify the images to compute the disparity map and do a dense 3D reconstruction.

The Computer Vision System Toolbox includes the `estimateCameraParameters` function that can be used to calibrate a stereo camera. This function will work, even if the resolutions are different. However, `rectifyStereoImages`, the stereo rectification function, assumes that the stereo images have the same size.

Comment: Thanks; well the device I am using is the new Kinect for windows V2 and I am trying to see how good the factory calibration is. So I do need to fine those calibration parameters again. So using a ROI approach in MATLAB would not work?

Comment: Hmm... Doesn't it only have one RGB camera? Are you trying to calibrate the RGB camera together with the IR camera?

Comment: Yes exactly. Thats what I am trying to do.

Comment: I am curious.  What kind of calibration pattern would you use, that would work for both RGB and IR?

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to measure? The Kinect does not use the RGB camera for the depth map. It gets the depth by using a pattern of infrared light read by the IR camera.

Comment: Well from what I read from the old Kinect, a checkeredboard would work for the case.But in the old one we could get both feeds at the same resolution. I just want to get the XYZ coordinates of a point wrt the kinect with factory calibration and then without

Comment: you can use a super resolution algorithm, to transform  the 512 X 412 to a higher resolution,

here is a link to an article about super resolution from a single image:

http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/single_image_SR/files/single_image_SR.pdf

Comment: A checkerboard would not work well for the IR camera... And as I've said before, the Kinect uses the IR camera-projector system to get depth, and not IR and RGB cams as a stereo pair. So even if you manage to calibrate, it will not be apples to apples comparison.

Comment: @Dima well I am aware of the fact that the IR camera-projector system is used to get the depth. However, if I want to map the color image onto the depth image so as to obtain the exact (X,Y,Z) world coordinates of something in the color image, I do need the rotation and translation matrix that maps the color camera onto the depth camera.